# Button setText() wouldn't actually setText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to setText() to

```
Button btnFloor, btnTable;
```

Which isn't working ATM, actually I'm trying to send data from

FloorsActivity -> TablesActivity -> NewOrdersActivity

So how I pass Data from a activity to another?

**FloorsActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onFloorItemClicked(int id) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TablesActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FloorId", id);
    startActivity(intent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Floor id : " + String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

**TablesActivity.java**

```
int floorId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_floors_tables);
    initViews();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    floorId = intent.getIntExtra("FloorId", 1);
}

@Override
public void onTableItemClicked(String name) {

    String floorName = "F" + floorId;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewOrderActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FloorId", floorId);
    intent.putExtra("TableName", name);
    intent.putExtra("FloorName", floorName);
    startActivity(intent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Table Name : " + String.valueOf(name), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

**NewOrderActivity.java**

```
String floorName;
String tableName;
int floorId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_order);
    initViews();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    floorName = intent.getStringExtra("FloorName");
    tableName = intent.getStringExtra("TableName");
    floorId = intent.getIntExtra("FloorId", 1);
}

public void initViews() {

    // Fetch view
    btnFloor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_floor);
    btnTable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_table);

    //Set Views

    btnFloor.setText(floorName);
    btnTable.setText(tableName);

    btnFloor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewOrderActivity.this, FloorsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewOrderActivity.this, TablesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("FloorId", floorId);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

NewOrdersActivity is where I'm trying to set text

Here is my commit on Github for this [full change](https://github.com/sooorajjj/KOT/commit/00041c49ef81e89ffccdf422cfa4c6b52b02bb05)
Here is the link to this [project](https://github.com/sooorajjj/KOT)

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. (I've suggested an edit to remove it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `initViews()` before you've overloaded the intent extra's.

Fixed **NewOrderActivity.java**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_order);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    floorName = intent.getStringExtra("FloorName");
    tableName = intent.getStringExtra("TableName");
    floorId = intent.getIntExtra("FloorId", 1);
    initViews();
}
```

Comment: Thanks , @whitebrow can you send me a pull request on github with this change ? just so i could keep your authorship for this change  .

Comment: Alas I do not have permission for a pull request :) Tried with desktop client.

Comment: i have sent an Github Collaborator invitation to your mail , Can you please check your mail inbox . Once you accept this invitation you can push directly to this repository

Comment: Thank you so much :) 

Please take a look at your hangouts